# Error in Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Tags: android, geolocation, appcelerator

I am developing an app with the geolocation services and there is no problem with iOS, but when I try to test it on Android, a location error occurs.

```
[ERROR] :  GeolocationModule: (main) [39266,89619] Unable to get current position, location is null
```

I don't know what happened because I have other apps working fine with the almost the same code.

Any help will be appreciated.

[Here is my Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA0at.png).

[here is my Xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ajel.png).

[here is preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI0xR.png).

[here is the next preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5mRF.png).

I am using SDK 7.0.2GA
Thanks in advance.

::EDIT::

i made some changes in the code using the sugestions.
Now the app stucks in the "location" event and stucks right there.

Thanks for the help

```
function SolicitarServicio( win, idservicio, datos, datosCompletos ){ 
       if(Titanium.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions(      Titanium.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_WHEN_IN_USE)) { 
          IniciarSolicitudDeServicios( win, idservicio, datos, datosCompletos     ); 
       }   
       else{
                 Ti.Geolocation.requestLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_WHEN_IN_USE, function(e) {
               if(!e.success){
                  Ti.API.info("*** No premissions: " + e.error );
                  Utiles.Alerta(L("error_permisos_geolocalizacion"));
                  return false;
               }
               else{
                  IniciarSolicitudDeServicios( win, idservicio, datos,     datosCompletos ); 
               }

         });  
       }
       function IniciarSolicitudDeServicios( win, idservicio, datos, datosCompletos ) {
           if( params.isAndroid ){            
               var gpsProvider = Ti.Geolocation.Android.createLocationProvider({
               name: Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS,
               });
               Ti.Geolocation.Android.addLocationProvider(gpsProvider);                      
           }        
           preloader.show(win);
           // The app stucks here, the if( e.success ) never happend
           Titanium.Geolocation.addEventListener("location",function(e){   
               if(e.success){    
                  preloader.hide(win);      
                  var latitud  = e.coords.latitude;
                  var longitud = e.coords.longitude;
                  Ti.API.info("*** Now get the coords and show te window");
                  var Button = require("src/common/Button");   
                  var WindowTotalBeige = require("src/common/ventanaTotal");   
                  var winServicio = new WindowTotalBeige("S", "G U A P P U R A" );
                  var vistaAgenda = require("src/vistas/solicitarServicio");
                  vistaAgenda.SolicitarServicio( winServicio, idservicio, datos, latitud, longitud, datosCompletos );    
                  winServicio.open();    
               }                  
               else{
                  preloader.hide(win);      
                  Utiles.Alerta( "ERROR: " +e.code + " " + e.error );
               }                                                            
           }); 
       }        
}
```

**SOLVED!!**
Updating the SDK to the 7.1.0 RC
No code changes.

Comment: please show your updated code using the event listener on stackoverflow, don't link to an image!

Comment: Nothing ? there is nothing i can do to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

GetCurrentLocation only returns a cached result of the location. You’ll need to watch for the location using the eventlistener.

Comment: Hi Rene, you mean the Titanium.Geolocation.addEventListener('location',function(){ ...... });  ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosSalinasOjeda
Is callback of requestLocationPermissions called on success for android?

Comment: hi @MitulBhalia, yes, is in the callback... i just compiled with the 7.1.0RC and the problem disapear with no code changes.. Should i answer my own question ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosSalinasOjeda Ok, thanks but i am using 6.0.2 as i need to use it because of some old modules.
If you did not make any changes in the code then you can update your question to show that you solved the issue with 7.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced the same issue in Motorla G4 plus devices using Ti SDK 7.5.0 GA. 
But when consulted with Appc team, they informed that GPS location fetching varies with device hardware. As per Appc support, "If you tested this indoors, then you may need to step outside to get a lock on the GPS satellite. Some GPS hardware is better than others. And it can sometimes take longer to connect than others as well.
Note that your code's preferred provider is GPS. This means the device won't "fallback" to fetching location from "WIFI" or the "cellular provider" while waiting for a GPS lock.
 This is not a software issue, and we are afraid that You're running into a hardware/physics limitation." But I was getting the location using Samsung smartphone in indoor as well.

I have verified this, by coming out of the building and I was able to get the location successfully using " Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) )," which was failing for me in indoor.

Comment: Also include ti.playservices to unlock better tracking of gps using FusedLocationProvider as mentioned in the docs https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation